# Custom format integer as date in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, date, datagrid, integer, custom-formatting

I have an integer field in my database that contains a date value in the form `yyyyMMdd`. Is it possible to parse this as a date in the form `dd/MM/yyyy` as bound to a datagrid?

Currently the field is bound like this:

```
<asp:boundcolumn datafield="access_date" headertext="Last logged on"></asp:boundcolumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **Date** for dates in database ?
You can convert int to datetime using following sample code:

```
var sdate = intdate.ToString();
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(sdate, "yyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The second line should be: var date = DateTime.ParseExact(sdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @anothershrubery in fact it should be `DateTime.ParseExact(sdate, "yyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Because the data model is fixed in an existing environment and I don't have influence on it.

Comment: Is this not possible to do directly as some kind of format specifier using `DataFormatString` on the `asp:BoundColumn` element? Your sollution requires that I do this in the DataBound event or something. I was really wondering if I could avoid that...

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But, you can define converting function on your aspx page and bind to it.

Comment: You can use binding expression, like that `Text="<%#ConvertFromInt(Eval("YourValueProperty"))%>" ` - ConvertFromInt is function in you page that takes int, and returns string or datetime.

Comment: OK - I found out what to do based on your answer and comments. See [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861854/custom-format-integer-as-date-in-datagrid/4862678#4862678) for how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **gor** for guiding me through this. 
His answer in itself was not the entire solution, but after some commenting back and forth, I ended up with a good solution.

Instead of using a `asp:boundcolumn` in the grid, I had to use `asp:templatecolumn` and display it through a binding expression (like **gor** explained in his comment, although I think he based his answer on using the `asp:listview` control, while I use the old `asp:datagrid` control).

### In the `<columns>` collection of the `asp:datagrid` control:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn headertext="Last logged on" >
<ItemTemplate><%#DateStringFromInt(Eval("access_date"))%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

### In the code-behind:

```
protected string DateStringFromInt(object value)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
        out date))
    {
        return date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    return value.ToString(); //Return original if not expected format
}
```